# Android Room Migration: Update Attribute Name By Creating New Table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-room

## Issue

In my project I a have a room table named '*content*' with a **Double** attribute '*archivedCount*'. In the latest version of the app the attribute *archivedCount* attribute is re-named to *dismissCount*, still as type **Double.**

#### Android API Level / SQL Version

*28 / 3.19*

#### Original Content model

```
@Entity(tableName = "content")
data class Content(@PrimaryKey var id: String, var archiveCount: Double) : Parcelable {...}
```

#### New Content model

```
@Entity(tableName = "content")
data class Content(@PrimaryKey var id: String, var dismissCount: Double) : Parcelable {...}
```

### Runtime error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle content(app.coinverse.content.models.Content).
```

I've inspected the Expected and Found tables the log prints and they appear to be identical.

## Attempted Solution

I attempted the [complex schema change](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/understanding-migrations-with-room-f01e04b07929) as outlined by a Google Developer Advocate unsuccessfully in order to modify the name of one attribute / column. Here is a basic version of what I attempted.

```
val MIGRATION_1_2: Migration = object : Migration(1, 2) {
override fun migrate(database: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
    // Create the new table
    database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE content_new (id TEXT, dismissCount REAL, PRIMARY KEY(id))")
    // Copy the data
    database.execSQL("INSERT INTO content_new (id, dismissCount) SELECT id, archiveCount FROM content")
    // Remove the old table
    database.execSQL("DROP TABLE content")
    // Change the table name to the correct one
    database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE content_new RENAME TO content")
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can't see anything wrong with your implementation, I would suggest that you use a different @Entity class that is not named Content() and try again.